# how can I solve run problem on type script file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, powershell, npm

[I want to use typescript on my project, I have successfully installed Machine Environment by using "npm i -g typescript" command, then I want run the .ts file by using "tsc file.ts" but I have get this problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvoj0.png)

Comment: The error message tells you the issue. Change your execution policy. Try to avoid posting links as well that only point to a picture of an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Step - 1 Open your terminal in Run As Administrator

Step - 2 Run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```